# Mysql self Join query with Limit never terminates

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, mysql-8.0, limits

I'm running an experiment with the query

```
Select  Distinct table_1.id1, table_2.id1
    FROM  image as table_1, image as table_2
    WHERE  table_1.id2 = table_2.id2
    LIMIT  K;
```

When I run the query without limit, it terminates after 8 hours. However, the query does not terminate for Limit 80000.

I'm running this on cloudLab with 100GB Ram and Below is the image of my.cnf and query plan. I'm not sure what is the bottle neck for my query. How should I solve this problem

Query Plan text:

```
| -> Limit: 80000 row(s)
  -> Table scan on <temporary>
        -> Temporary table with deduplication
            -> Limit table size: 80000 unique row(s)
                -> Inner hash join (table_2.id2 = table_1.id2)  (cost=48913990425076.15 rows=48913988916980)
                    -> Table scan on table_2  (cost=0.01 rows=22116507)
                    -> Hash
                       -> Table scan on table_1  (cost=2224194.70 rows=22116507)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question, and replace the screenshots with real text; the second one is almost illegible, and impossible to cut and paste from a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure why you need to cut and paste from the query plan. but I'll edit it anyway

Comment: Except for the buffer_pool_size, do _not_ blindly raise lots of settings.  Probably none of those settings should be over 1% of RAM.  How much swap space do you have?  Was it swapping?